# filter data gained from NSURL

Tags: objective-c, ios

I know how to fetch data from NSSURL, but i wana ask how i can filter the data like the page contains both text, images , videos etc how i can specify like only to extract images. And lets say if all the data is downloaded all together how i can filter it.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{


    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

Like in this how i can filter if all the data is downloaded all together. or to specify the type of data before downloading. thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `NSURLResponse` you can check MIMEType

```
NSURLResponse * httpResponse = (NSURLResponse *) response;
NSString *fileMIMEType = [[httpResponse MIMEType] lowercaseString];
```

You can consider using this delegate method for `NSURLConnection`

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

   NSString *mime = [response MIMEType];
   //do something with mime
}
```